# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. please review my code

Tags: php, soap

I'm not really familiar working with soap.
I wanted to pull data from soap server, but it seems there are problem (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.).
Here the debug code from my code:

```
stdClass Object ( [GetSalesBannersResult] => stdClass Object ( [Result] => [Message] => Object reference not set to an instance of an object. [List] => stdClass Object ( ) ) )
Request :<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://ws.ozsale.com.au/API/V2"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:GetSalesBanners><ns1:saleCategoryID>40F80218-A9E1-43C4-96FF-4C046D192A21</ns1:saleCategoryID><ns1:getTopThree>true</ns1:getTopThree></ns1:GetSalesBanners></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Response:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><GetSalesBannersResponse xmlns="http://ws.ozsale.com.au/API/V2"><GetSalesBannersResult><Result>false</Result><Message>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</Message><List /></GetSalesBannersResult></GetSalesBannersResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

and it is my code so far:

```
<?php
// create a connection to the local host mono .NET pull back the wsdl to get the functions names
  // and also the parameters and return values
  $client = new SoapClient("http://www.ozsale.com.au/api/v2/api.asmx?WSDL",
    array(
      "trace"      => 1,    // enable trace to view what is happening
      "exceptions" => 0,    // disable exceptions
      "cache_wsdl" => 0) 
  );

  // get a response from the WSDL zend server function getQuote for the day monday
  print_r($client->GetSalesBanners(array(
    "saleCategoryID" => "40F80218-A9E1-43C4-96FF-4C046D192A21", 
    "getTopThree" =>"1"
    ))
  );
  //print_r($client);

  // display what was sent to the server (the request)
  echo "<p>Request :".htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest()) ."</p>";
  // display the response from the server
  echo "<p>Response:".htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponse())."</p>";
  ?>
```

and then the api documentation for is here http://www.ozsale.com.au/api/v2/api.asmx?op=GetSalesBanners

Anyone could help figure out whether what is wrong here...

---

New update of my question. now the document api is here http://www.ozsale.com.au/api/v2/api.asmx?op=GetPublicSalesBanners

I attempt to pull data with these following info:

```
'saleCategoryID' => '40F80218-A9E1-43C4-96FF-4C046D192A21',
'countryID'=> 'AS',
'languageID'=> 'EN', 
'getTopThree' =>'1'
```

My code is here:

```
<?php
// create a connection to the local host mono .NET pull back the wsdl to get the functions names
  // and also the parameters and return values
  $client = new SoapClient("http://www.ozsale.com.au/api/v2/api.asmx?WSDL",
    array(
      "trace"      => 1,    // enable trace to view what is happening
      "exceptions" => 0,    // disable exceptions
      "cache_wsdl" => 0) 
  );

  // get a response from the WSDL zend server function getQuote for the day monday
  print_r($client->GetPublicSalesBanners(array(
    'saleCategoryID' => '40F80218-A9E1-43C4-96FF-4C046D192A21',
    'countryID'=> 'AS',
    'languageID'=> 'EN', 
    'getTopThree' =>'1'
    ))
  );

  // display what was sent to the server (the request)
  echo "<p>Request :".htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest()) ."</p>";
  // display the response from the server
  echo "<p>Response:".htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponse())."</p>";
  ?>
```

And when I trying to see how it work, it's output like this:

```
SoapFault Object ( [message:protected] => Server was unable to process request. ---> There was an error generating the XML document. ---> <>f__AnonymousType2a`2[System.String,System.Object[]] cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor. [string:Exception:private] => [code:protected] => 0 [file:protected] => /Users/resarahman/Documents/xampp/htdocs/testing/soap/test.php [line:protected] => 17 [trace:Exception:private] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [file] => /Users/resarahman/Documents/xampp/htdocs/testing/soap/test.php [line] => 17 [function] => __call [class] => SoapClient [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => GetPublicSalesBanners [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [saleCategoryID] => 40F80218-A9E1-43C4-96FF-4C046D192A21 [countryID] => AS [languageID] => EN [getTopThree] => 1 ) ) ) ) [1] => Array ( [file] => /Users/resarahman/Documents/xampp/htdocs/testing/soap/test.php [line] => 17 [function] => GetPublicSalesBanners [class] => SoapClient [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [saleCategoryID] => 40F80218-A9E1-43C4-96FF-4C046D192A21 [countryID] => AS [languageID] => EN [getTopThree] => 1 ) ) ) ) [previous:Exception:private] => [faultstring] => Server was unable to process request. ---> There was an error generating the XML document. ---> <>f__AnonymousType2a`2[System.String,System.Object[]] cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor. [faultcode] => soap:Server [detail] => )
Request :<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://ws.ozsale.com.au/API/V2"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:GetPublicSalesBanners><ns1:saleCategoryID>40F80218-A9E1-43C4-96FF-4C046D192A21</ns1:saleCategoryID><ns1:countryID>AS</ns1:countryID><ns1:languageID>EN</ns1:languageID><ns1:getTopThree>true</ns1:getTopThree></ns1:GetPublicSalesBanners></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Response:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; There was an error generating the XML document. ---&gt; &lt;&gt;f__AnonymousType2a`2[System.String,System.Object[]] cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.</faultstring><detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Any idea why and what is wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

Your inputs look OK, unless there are any special requirements such as a SOAP header. That's most likely a problem with the web service that the provider needs to fix, rather than a problem with your client code. I suggest contacting them.